# XAML Schemas combined in one url

Tags: wpf, xaml, schema

I have a problem with the size of a XAML file. It contains a lot of schemas like

```
<FixedPage Width="816" Height="1056" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06" xml:lang="und">
```

Is it allowed or possible to combine needed schemas on my own website as URL and include my url as single schema namespace?

Regards

Comment: Those are not URLs, they look like it but they are just URIs which uniquely identify a namespace. [There is an attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) used to map different namespaces to one URI.

Comment: Again H.B. with a first answer. Kind Regards for that. H.B., you say, there is no chance to decrease files by replacing the xmlns's because there are no url's but namespace declarations? Right?

Comment: No, i am only saying that those strings have nothing to do with websites even though they look like URLs. I have no idea if you can combine namespace declarations in a way that WPF will understand (if i did i would have posted an answer).

Comment: Thanks H.B. I think that will already be the answer!

Comment: I thought about the possibilities and wrote an answer while you commented, did you come to a similar conclusion? (And if not you could answer your own question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comment WPF uses [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) to map namespaces in an assembly to URIs, as those attributes are defined on assemblies you will not be able to change the mappings on existing assemblies. You could of course map your own namespaces to the same XML namespace but that probably is not such a good idea.